# java web application -servlet that detects a request

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been given a very difficult task on how to use a servlet to retrieve a web request from an android phone and display the value using the eclipse program. For example, when an android phone sends a web request to the serlvet with a value of "Good Day", the serlvet must be able to detect the value Good Day" and display the value. I have no idea of how to go about doing it.

How can I go about doing this? Note that my task is considered to be more of a back-end coding.

My question is whether do i have to write any codes in the doGET and doPost method in order for the servlet to be able to retrieve the request or is there any ways to do it?

thanks.

Comment: Please try telling us less about your feeling and more about what, exactly, you are trying to do. What do you mean, 'send a web request'? HTTP POST? HTTP GET? HTTP PUT?

Comment: Yeah, servlets don't display stuff. You ask them stuff and they respond with stuff. That's it. Of course, you could get the servlet to modify a JSP or something like that. I'd start reading some Tomcat tutorials or something. Maybe you could set up a LAMP stack (or WAMP stack if you are on Windows)...Either way, tutorials are your friend. This is not an impossible task, but (considering the context of the question) I can tell you aren't familiar with these things, and therefore, this will probably take you a bit of effort. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you should put some effort into working out how servlets and http requests work before posting the same question for the third time.

Comment: You ask them stuff and they respond with stuff. How does they do that?

Answer (score 1):

A request coming from an android phone is no different than a request coming from a browser, so `doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)`, req would be what you need.

What do you mean by "a request with a value of "Good Day""? A parameter like in /some_servlet?msg=good_day? To get this you'd use req.getParameter("msg").

Comment: How do i go about doing this? What codes are needed to be type in the doGet and doPost method? Maybe that one is not important

Comment: Should i create a new web dynamic web application or an android application?

Comment: I don't know enough to tell you that, but you should definitely first familiarize yourself with servlets, so go and read a servlet tutorial.